# Cannot Get Error from getObject API to download/get an object(audio file) from S3

Tags: node.js, api, amazon-s3

My call recordings of amazon connect are being stored on S3 in .wav file, i am looking to get and play those recordings in a third party application. For this i am using `getObject API` & trying to get/download the .wav files by name but i am getting the **`Cannot Get Error`**.
At the same time i do want to provide the path in key **`e.g. Connect/Lab/2022/04/08/abc.wav`**, is it possible?
How to resolve it? here is my code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const expres = require("express");
const app = expres();
app.listen(3001);

const aws = require("aws-sdk");

aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_SECRET,
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.REGION
})

const BUCKET = process.env.BUCKET
const Key = '/connect/oblab2/CallRecordings/2022/04/08/'
const s3 = new aws.S3(secretAccessKey = process.env.ACCESS_SECRET, accessKeyId = process.env.ACCESS_KEY);

 app.get("/download/filename", async(req, res)=>{
    const filename = req.params.filename
    let x = await s3.getObject({Bucket:BUCKET, Key:Key + filename}).promise();
    res.send(x.Body);
})
```

Comment: Did you write correct policy for your S3 bucket?

Comment: yeah,

```{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::new-bucket-for-metrics"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::new-bucket-for-metrics/*"]
    }
  ]
}```

Comment: Where's `Principal` in that policy?

Answer (score 0):

Achieved the goal through:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const expres = require("express");
const app = expres();

app.listen(3001);

app.get('/getfilefromS3', async (req, res, next) => {

  aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: process.env.ACCESS_SECRET,
    accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.REGION
  })

  const s3 = new aws.S3(secretAccessKey = process.env.ACCESS_SECRET, accessKeyId = process.env.ACCESS_KEY);

  var params = { Bucket: process.env.BUCKET, Key: "connect/oblab2/CallRecordings/2022/04/08/" + req.query.filename };

  s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.status(200);
      res.end('Error Fetching File');
    }
    else {
      res.attachment(params.Key); // Set Filename
      res.type(data.ContentType); // Set FileType
      res.send(data.Body);        // Send File Buffer
    }
  });

})
```

And than hitting endpoint `http://localhost:3001/getfilefromS3?filename=filename.wav`